# Be notified of change in a setting in Settings Bundle (in Xamarin iOS)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I would like my app to be notified of a change in one of the settings in the settings bundle. Or if that's not possible, of any change (and I will then check if it was that specific setting).

How would I achieve that in Xamarin iOS?

It seems like one of those options is addressed in these answers [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3928064/939213) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525893/939213). But I can't figure out how to do that in Xamarin/C#.

Answer (score 1):

Just translate the Objective-C code to C# and if you read the [document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsvaluetransformer.userdefaultsdidchangenotification?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12), you will find there are some examples:

**// Lambda style**

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(

    NSValueTransformer.UserDefaultsDidChangeNotification, (notification) => { Console.WriteLine("Received the notification NSValueTransformer", notification); }

);
```

**//Method style**

```
void Callback(NSNotification notification)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Received a notification NSValueTransformer", notification);
}

void Setup()
{
    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(NSValueTransformer.UserDefaultsDidChangeNotification, Callback);
}
```

Refer: [userdefaultsdidchangenotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsvaluetransformer.userdefaultsdidchangenotification?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to find which setting was it that was changed?

Comment: @ispiro Can you please mark this answer and I saw you opened an new issue about this new problem, I have added my answer there. Thanks.