# How to update Preferences when global settings in iOS are changed at runtime in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

my problem is the following: I would like to update the Preferences (Xamarin.Essentials) when global settings of my application in iOS are changed at runtime.

I know that I have to use NSUserDefaults in order to access the global settings or respectively what is written in root.plist-file. I've also read the following: [Be notified of change in a setting in Settings Bundle (in Xamarin iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58261458/be-notified-of-change-in-a-setting-in-settings-bundle-in-xamarin-ios). But I don't know how to handle that. In the iOS part of my Xamarin project I have the AppDelegate-class but I don't know which method to call in order to change the preferences by NSUserDefaults. Could you help me?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

> How to update Preferences when global settings in iOS are changed at
> runtime in Xamarin

If you want to update the Preferences (Xamarin.Essentials) from native ios platform, a simple method is to use [Xamarin.Forms MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center).You can send message by method `MessagingCenter.Send` in xamarin ios and you can receive message in method `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` in forms app, here you can update the Preferences (Xamarin.Essentials).

The Xamarin.Forms [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.messagingcenter?view=xamarin-forms) class implements the publish-subscribe pattern, allowing message-based communication between components that are inconvenient to link by object and type references. This mechanism allows publishers and subscribers to communicate without having a reference to each other, helping to reduce dependencies between them.

Publishers send messages using the [MessagingCenter.Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.messagingcenter.send?view=xamarin-forms) method, while subscribers listen for messages using the [MessagingCenter.Subscribe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.messagingcenter.subscribe?view=xamarin-forms) method. In addition, subscribers can also unsubscribe from message subscriptions, if required, with the [MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.messagingcenter.unsubscribe?view=xamarin-forms) method.

**Publish a message**

MessagingCenter messages are strings. Publishers notify subscribers of a message with one of the `MessagingCenter.Send` overloads.

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, string>(this, "Hi", "John");
```

**Subscribe to a message**

Subscribers can register to receive a message using one of the MessagingCenter.Subscribe overloads. The following code example shows an example of this:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, string>(this, "Hi", async (sender, arg) =>
{
    await DisplayAlert("Message received", "arg=" + arg, "OK");
});
```

For more details, you can check:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center .